# How to force set test status to 'Passed' in MSTest?

Tags: c#, mstest

Can you please suggest how to force set test status to 'Passed' in MSTest?
Say I have 2 reruns of the same test -- one is failed, second is passed but the outcome is 'FAILED' anyway... I need to make it 'PASSED'.
Here is the sample of the code that re-run tests. But it still shows test result as 'Failed' in the final output if the first run is failed and the second run is passed

```
protected void BaseTestCleanup(TestContext testContext, UITestBase type)
{ 
    if (testContext.CurrentTestOutcome != UnitTestOutcome.Passed)
    {
        if (!typeof(UnitTestAssertException).IsAssignableFrom(LastException.InnerException.GetType()))
        {
            var instanceType = type.GetType();
            var testMethod = instanceType.GetMethod(testContext.TestName);
            testMethod.Invoke(type, null);                    
        }
    }                
}
```

Comment: "force"?  At what point?  Why do you need to lie about what happened with the test? Why can't you just either A) return a failed status of the actual test B) Don't base your cleanup action on the current test outcome.

Comment: Nope, this is a particularity of the test flow. Some tests are running on low resources and sometimes fail (and this is ok I just need to re-run them). The general output has to be passed in the end even if it failed once.

Comment: Nope.  It's not okay that your tests sometimes run low on resources and need to be re-run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TestCleanup` method is too late for checking `UnitTestOutcome`. If for whatever reason you want to run your test twice, you have to create your own `TestMethodAttribute` and override `Execute` method in there. Here is an example how you can do that:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    public class MyTestMethodAttribute : TestMethodAttribute
    {
        public override TestResult[] Execute(ITestMethod testMethod)
        {
            TestResult[] results = base.Execute(testMethod);

            bool runTestsAgain = false;

            foreach (TestResult result in results)
            {
                if (result.Outcome == UnitTestOutcome.Failed)
                {
                    result.Outcome = UnitTestOutcome.Passed;
                    runTestsAgain = true;
                }
            }

            if (runTestsAgain)
            {
                // Run them again I guess...
            }

            return results;
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [MyTestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(false);
        }
    }
}
```

With this solution your tests will be always green.

Comment: Thank you very much!